# joining in C# for two condtions

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have to do conditional joining between two tables Price and Operator

### Table Prices

1. CustomerName
2. UnitPrice
3. Country
4. Code

### Table Operators

1. OpertorName
2. Country
3. Code

Joining requires to be run on following two conditions:

a. If Code is null for a record in table Prices
 then join only on basis of Country (all Codes of selected Country will be included from table Operators)

b. If Code is present for a record in table Prices
  then join on basis of both Country and Code

Please help

```
//If Code is null in table Price for a record then :

 var reportList = (from pl in Prices
                          join ml in Operators 
                          on pl.Country equals ml.Country                          
                          select new PriceReports {  }

//If Code is present in table Price for a record then 

    var reportList = (from pl in Prices
                          join ml in Operators 
                          on new { a = pl.Country, b = pl.MNC } equals new { a = ml.Country, b = ml.Code }
                          select new PriceReports {  }
```

I want to create a single query to represent both above conditions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot write joins like this with the used join syntax in LinQ, you need to use a cross join with where conditions.

```
var reportList = from pl in PriceS
                 from ml in Operators.Where(mList => mList.Country == pl.Country
                                                   && (pl.Code == null || mList.Code == pl.Code))
                 select new PriceReports {  }
```

Comment: will this approve both conditions?

Comment: @NextOlive It joins the table with the condition given in the where-function. In this case the same `(CountryRegion.)Name/Country` and `Code` is null OR same `Code/MNC`.

Comment: it is picking only the not null records (the second condition)

Comment: @NextOlive You were right, I checked for `Code== null` in the Operators data, you needed it in the prices data. I fixed it and also changed the `MNC`-Property to `Code` as described in your table definition (in opposing to MNC in your sample).